# How to assign permenant LAN address?

Tags: static-ip

I want my Pi to have a permanent IP when accessing via LAN (i.e. http://192.168.1.10/, not the web), so I don't have to search for it every time. My router settings will not allow me to do this (It's an ISP provided, with limited settings).

I have my Pi 3B running Raspbian Lite.

Comment: What is a "permenant(sic) LAN address"? What have you tried? See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: One that doesn't change every time the router wants it to. @Milliways

Comment: What you mean is a static ip address. You have an internet router and the Raspberry Pi on your network. What are the other devices? What operating system they are running?

Answer (score 1):

Use the hostname as a means to eliminate an IP change messing you up. You just put the .local on it so it will search on the local network for that host.

```
MacUser2525:~$ ssh zeus@buster-raspi.local
Linux buster-raspi 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 (2020-12-31) aarch64
snip...
Last login: Mon Mar  1 17:54:07 2021 from fe80::1003:5492:80fa:2bc5%eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Pi to be assigned a **predictable IP Address** you can *request* the DHCP server to assign one.
E.g. Adding the following to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` will request an address on *wlan0* and on *eth0*.

```
interface wlan0
request 192.168.1.99

interface eth0
request 192.168.1.98
```

If you request an IP Address **within the range managed by the DHCP server** which **is available** this should be honoured, otherwise the DHCP server will allocate an address as normal.

Comment: real noob here, how do I add to a file?

Comment: You will have to learn how to edit system files. Most use something like `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf` I prefer  `sudoedit /etc/dhcpcd.conf` (which is safer), but not sure if this requires other configuration. I suggest you practice editing on some other files. **ALWAYS** make a copy **BEFORE** editing **ANY** system file.